# Android: debug shared library

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, gdb

I'd like to debug android NDK application, more precisely - I want to check what arguments (<s>r4 - r8</s> r1 - r4 registers) are passed to function from shared library in apk.

What I have tried:

- I've run gdbserver :1234 --attach  on the device
- I've run arm-linux-androideabi-gdb from ndk package by Google on the PC
- I've set solib-search-path and written target remote :1234

So far, so good. Now I try to set breakpoint (`break <function name>`) (function name from 
objdump), but I get repond: `Cannot access memory at address <...>`. `info shared` says the library is loaded, Does it mean I can't set breakpoint there? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you realize that registers r4-r8 are _not_ function arguments in the AAPCS? Registers r0-r3 are the first 4 arguments, the rest go on the stack. To quote: "_The first four registers r0-r3 (a1-a4) are used to pass argument values into a subroutine and to return a result value from a function. They may also be used to hold intermediate values within a routine (but, in general, only between subroutine calls)._" and "_A subroutine must preserve the contents of the registers r4-r8, r10, r11 and SP (and r9 in PCS variants that designate r9 as v6)._"

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info (I have found info about registers r4-r8 somewhere in the net), any ideas how to set breakpoint to function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The ndk-build skript does much more then you would expect.**
One of the things it to copy both the **gdbserver**, a file called **gbd.setup** and the generated .so
 into a hidden folder called .**obj/armei/**
There you will have to add the libraries you would like to debug because the symbols are 
referencing them.
The libraries are copied from the device to your PC by some adb shell pull - commands.
**I wrote an article about the topic at:** http://www.professional-android-development.com/articles/android-ndk-large-c-projects

When placing the libraries into the right folder, you can set your breakpoints. 
Still, for some internal reasons, they can fail.
In this case run ndk-gdb --start (the first try will also fail), enforce the application to close and rerun ndk-gdb --start (this time not forcing the application to close).

Comment: However, can I use this if I don't have source?

Comment: Yes, if the libraries you want to debug are build with debugging symbols. So it depends on how the shared library was compiled (-g option). If it is a library from the AOSP, you could try building it yourself , but this would require a rooted smartphone and installing the library in the right place. If it is a third - party - library to which you don't have access, you could ask their support if a debuggable version of the library is available.

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot access memory at address <...>" usually means there is a mismatch between the .so file on your PC and the .so file that is on Android. Did you recompile and reinstall?

Btw, what is the reason you're not using "ndk-gdb"? That's a script (part of the NDK) that takes care of all the gory details for you.

Comment: ndk-gdb requires source, doesn't it?